# Using Splunk rex to extract String from logs

Tags: splunk

From splunk logs,how can I get a count of all those methods whose **Time taken is > 10ms?**
Splunk logs which look some thing like this :

> c.s.m.c.advice.ExecutionTimeAdvice       : <>
> relationId = aa12 | Method Name = methodA() Time taken  is = 0ms
>
> c.s.m.c.advice.ExecutionTimeAdvice       : <>
> relationId = ab12 | Method Name = methodA(). Time taken is = 15ms
>
> c.s.m.c.advice.ExecutionTimeAdvice       : <>
> relationId = ab12 | Method Name = methodB(). Time taken is = 1ms

Answer (score 2):

This would be the general idea:

```
| rex field=_raw "Name = (?<methodName>\w+)\("
| rex field=_raw "s = (?<duration>\d+)\D"
| where duration > 10
| stats count by methodName
```

Within your search, you will need to

1. Create a `rex` field to grab the method name
2. Create a `rex` field to grab the duration in milliseconds
3. Use the `where` command to filter the results to where your new "duration" field > 10ms
4. Use the `stats` command with `count by` to count the current results, binning by your new "methodName" field

If this is not exactly correct for your logs, it should at least get you very close.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.Will try it out.

Comment: For some reason,rex field=_raw "s = (?<duration>\d+)\D" did not find any match.I then used rex field=_raw "s = (?<duration>\d+)" .When I do this,duration is received as 1,3 etc.Meaning only the first digit of the number is retrieved.I thought using d+ would match all the digits.

Comment: I was able to resolve the above.Thanks